# Battery not detected on my embedded device on reboot

Tags: linux, boot, battery

I have an ARM based embedded device with Linux Kernel 2.6.31 running on it. I have seen that while rebooting the device sometimes battery won't get detected and the device will just fail to boot. Any pointers on :

1. What is the root cause of this problem?
2. How can I find the root cause of this problem?
3. What can I do to fix this?
4. Is this a software or hardware bug?

Comment: How do you know the battery isn't detected if it fails to boot?

Comment: I can see the logs while it is booting and it clearly says in the boots logs : No battery found
ERROR: === BATTERY ID IS INVALID. STOPPING BOOT ===

Comment: This could be either hardware or software, but I'd bet the software is not giving enough time for the hardware to initialize.

Comment: Question is unanswerable in its current form.  This kind of problem is highly hardware dependent, and you aren't really describing the hardware.

Comment: @psusi I asked this question to get people's thoughts on this matter. I think, one of the goals of this forum is to discuss seemingly intractable problems. And are you saying that only answerable questions need to be posted here? How would you know that a question is answerable without posting it?

Comment: @abc: none of the Stack Exchange sites are forums. And discussions are not what these sites are about. Please recheck the [faq], questions need to be answerable (even if the answer is "that's impossible" or something like that). psusi is asking for details about your hardware that might make your question answerable.